# windows 2012 r2 rdp lost connection every 5 seconds

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a weird problem, windows 2012 r2 rdp established but lost the connection every 10 seconds (windows vps from several providers ) I have tried windows 2008 vps and the connection works without any problem

solutions I have tried without success:

- reinstall my local machine OS
- reinstall vps OS
- changed my local machine from windows 8.1 to windows 7
- access the vps from another PC
- using another remote desktop software
- disable all firewall and anti virus on my local machine

Comment: Things to consider: `1.` telnet to port 3389 from the client to the server and see what results you get. `2.` check the server event viewer logs and see if anything there gives more clue. `3.` see what NIC driver version you have on the server OS and see if there are any updates at that level. `4.` check server NIC features related to offloading and play around with disabling those perhaps or researching to see if others have had similiar issues with those functions. These are quick ideas for troubleshooting the issue since you've went to the extreme of reinstalling the server OS.

Comment: Some users report conflict with Dell Printer drivers. 
Try this Hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2897602/fix-tcp-connections-that-use-ephemeral-loopback-addresses-are-dropped-suddenly-in-windows